# Sorting with thrust library on gpu

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv, cuda, thrust

I work on stereovision and I have a problem with `sort` from te Thrust library. When I use it in my kernel function, the application run and bug because all the kernels aren't launch in my `<<< >>>` call but when I remove the `sort` all works (but the result isn't good). I have searched for alternatives but I have found nothing except Thrust for GPU sort. Thanks

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/equal.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const int correlationWindow = 81;
const int widthWindow = (int)sqrt((float)correlationWindow);
const int searchWindow = 52;

__constant__ int widthWindow2 = 9;

__device__
void makeVector(float *mat, float *vec, int col, int x, int y) {
    int ind = 0;
    for (int i = x; i < x + widthWindow2; i++) {
        for (int j = y; j < y + widthWindow2; j++) {
            vec[ind] = mat[col * i + j];
            ind++;
        }
    }
}

__device__
void disparityUpdate2(int i, int j, int col, int distance, float *d_disparity) {
    d_disparity[col * i + j] = ((255 / searchWindow) * distance);
}

void resize(float *d_disparity, Mat &disparity) {
    for (int i = 0; i < disparity.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < disparity.cols; j++) {
            int ind = disparity.cols * i + j;
            disparity.at<float>(i, j) = d_disparity[ind];
        }
    }
}

__global__
void computeSMAD2(int minX, float *d_mL, float *d_mR, float *dif, float *windowL, float *windowR, float  *d_disparity, int colmLO, int colmL, int seachWindow) {
    int mini;

    int pOiX(threadIdx.x + minX); // + minX
    int pOiY(blockIdx.x + minX);
    int newPoIx(max(minX, pOiX - searchWindow));
    int newPoIy(pOiY); 
    /*int pOiX(pox);
    int pOiY(poy);
    int newPoIx(npox);
    int newPoIy(npoy); */
    int minPoIx(newPoIx);
    int smad = 0;
    int bMax = (int)(correlationWindow / 2);

    makeVector(d_mL, windowL, colmL, pOiY, pOiX); // ATTENTION ligne / colonne
    makeVector(d_mR, windowR, colmL, newPoIy, newPoIx);

    for (int h = 0; h < correlationWindow; h++) {
        dif[h] = windowL[h] - windowR[h];
    }

    thrust::sort(thrust::seq, dif, dif + correlationWindow);

    int median = dif[(correlationWindow - 1) / 2];

    for (int h = 0; h < correlationWindow; h++) {
        dif[h] = abs(dif[h] - median);
    }

    thrust::sort(thrust::seq, dif, dif + correlationWindow);

    for (int i = 0; i <= bMax - 1; i++) {
        smad = smad + pow(dif[i], 2);
    }

    mini = smad;

    newPoIx++;

    for (int i = newPoIx; i <= pOiX; i++) {
        smad = 0;
        makeVector(d_mR, windowR, colmL, newPoIy, i);

        for (int h = 0; h < correlationWindow; h++) {
            dif[h] = windowL[h] - windowR[h];
        }

        thrust::sort(thrust::seq, dif, dif + correlationWindow);

        median = dif[(correlationWindow - 1) / 2];

        for (int h = 0; h < correlationWindow; h++) {
            dif[h] = abs(dif[h] - median);
        }

        thrust::sort(thrust::seq, dif, dif + correlationWindow);

        for (int j = 0; j <= bMax - 1; j++) {
            if (smad < mini) {
                smad = smad + pow(dif[j], 2);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (smad < mini) {
            mini = smad;
            minPoIx = i;
        }
    }
    int distance = pOiX - minPoIx;

    d_disparity[colmLO * (pOiY - minX) + (pOiX - minX)] = ((255 / searchWindow) * distance);
}

Mat SMAD2(int minX, Mat mLO, Mat mRO) {
    Mat mL = Mat::zeros(mLO.rows + 2 * minX, mLO.cols + 2 * minX, CV_32FC1);
    Mat mR = Mat::zeros(mLO.rows + 2 * minX, mLO.cols + 2 * minX, CV_32FC1);
    Mat disparity = Mat::zeros(mRO.rows, mRO.cols, CV_32FC1);

    mLO.copyTo(mL.rowRange(minX, mL.rows - minX).colRange(minX, mL.cols - minX));
    mRO.copyTo(mR.rowRange(minX, mL.rows - minX).colRange(minX, mL.cols - minX));

    float *d_mL, *windowL;
    float *d_mR, *windowR;
    float *dif;
    float *d_disparity;

    cudaMallocManaged(&dif, correlationWindow * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&windowL, correlationWindow * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&windowR, correlationWindow * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&d_mL, mL.rows * mL.cols * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&d_mR, mR.rows * mR.cols * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&d_disparity, disparity.rows * disparity.cols * sizeof(float)); 

    /*dif = new float[correlationWindow];
    windowL = new float[correlationWindow];
    windowR = new float[correlationWindow];
    d_mL = new float[mL.rows * mL.cols];
    d_mR = new float[mR.rows * mR.cols];
    d_disparity = new float[disparity.rows * disparity.cols]; */


    memcpy(d_mL, mL.data, mL.rows * mL.cols * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(d_mR, mR.data, mR.rows * mR.cols * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(d_disparity, disparity.data, disparity.rows * disparity.cols * sizeof(float));

    int ind = 0;
    int colmL = mL.cols;
    int colmLO = mLO.cols;
    int npox, npoy;

    clock_t begin = clock();

    computeSMAD2 <<<70, 50>>>(minX, d_mL, d_mR, dif, windowL, windowR, d_disparity, mLO.cols, mL.cols, searchWindow);
    //computeSMAD2 <<<mLO.rows, mLO.cols>>>(minX, d_mL, d_mR, dif, windowL, windowR, d_disparity, mLO.cols, mL.cols, searchWindow);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    /*
    for (int poy = minX; poy < mR.rows - minX; poy++) {
        for (int pox = minX; pox < mR.cols - minX; pox++) {
            //////////////////////// DE GAUCHE A DROITE
            npox = max(minX, pox - searchWindow);
            npoy = poy;

            computeSMAD2(minX, d_mL, d_mR, disparity, d_disparity, windowL, windowR, dif, colmLO, colmL, pox, poy, npox, npoy);

            ind++;
        }
    } */

    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "time " << elapsed_secs << endl;

    cudaFree(dif);
    cudaFree(windowL);
    cudaFree(windowR);
    cudaFree(d_mL);
    cudaFree(d_mR);
    cudaFree(d_disparity); 

    return disparity;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int minX = (int)floor((float)(widthWindow / 2));

    Mat mL2 = Mat::ones(70, 50, CV_8UC1) * 255;
    Mat mR2 = Mat::zeros(70, 50, CV_8UC1);

    Mat disparity = SMAD2(minX, mL2, mR2);

    disparity.convertTo(disparity, CV_8UC1);
    Mat im;
    hconcat(mL2, mR2, im);
    hconcat(im, disparity, im); imshow("test", im); waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is wrong. as I see, all threads will sort the same array **dif**. It caused memory violation.

Comment: Thank you, I have change this and windowL and windowR. Now program run with Nsight debug without any error but not with visual compiler I have a problem and when I run the window compiler I have a "unable memory access" for d_disparity. Why ?